# SP13 Calendar Add+ Not Appearing

Tags: 2013, calendar, settings

This is pretty odd.  Normally in SP13 calendars if you hover on the date Add+ will appear (for example see image below).  However, I have a calendar that does not operate in that matter.  When I hover over the date or anywhere within the calendar Add+ does not appear.

[image]
Has anyone experienced this issue where Add+ does not appear when the end-user hovers over the date or anywhere on the calendar?

Comment: Does the user have permission to add new events?

Comment: @RJCuthbertson Thank you for your response.  Yes, the user does have permissions to add new events.  On the other calendars located on the site the user is able to add an event using +Add that appears.  However, in this one calendar does not allow to add using +Add.  Thanks!

Comment: Are there any JavaScript errors in the console? Is the branding different in this library? Is there anything else on the page? If you create a new view on this library do you have the same issue?

Comment: @RJCuthbertson There's CSS on the page that hides dates from the calendar view.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if this relates to your problem. but we had the same problem when we had a custom masterpage with css+javascript that was breaking calendar +Add to appear.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I created a custom list and then created a Calendar view for it. I even tried adding the Event content type and making it the default (as opposed to the default Item content type). Still didn't fix it. Only thing I could think do was remake the list as a true Calendar list. That fixed it.